# Grabbing the classes of the divs that are visible and then adding a . to the front of each class that was found

Tags: jquery

Trying to grab the class names of the `divs` that are visible and then `prepend` an decimal to the class names I get.
Any help would be great, thanks.

Here is what I have so far.

```
$('#imagefiles ul li img').click(function() {
    var open = $(".open:visible").attr("class");
    var n = open.split(",");
    alert(n);
});
```

Only one `div` will be visible and that `div` will have two class names.
The whole point of getting the class names like this is so I can `append` an image to the open folder with the `<div class="edititable">` in it. When I try this code nothing happens. any thoughts?

```
$('#imagefiles ul li img').click(function() {
    //Get the source of the image that was clicked
    var img = $(this).attr('src');

    //Grab the class name of the opened folder and prepend a decimal to it.
    var classes = $(".open:visible").attr("class").split(" ");
    var classesWithDot = "";

    $.each(classes, function (index, value) {
        classesWithDot += " ." + value;
    });

    $(' + classesWithDot + ').find('.edititable').append('<img src="' + img + '" style="width:30%; height:30%;" ">');

});
```

Comment: the value i get back will have two class names in it. each div with the class of .open has another class name that is unique. so if i get back a value of 'open HTML5' i want to add a decimal to the front of each one so the outcome will be .open .HTML5

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wf9u9/

```
$('#imagefiles ul li img').click(function() {
   var classes = $(".open:visible").attr("class").split(" ");
   var classesWithDot = "";

   $.each(classes, function (index, value) {
       classesWithDot += " ." + value;
   });

   alert(classesWithDot);
});
```

Comment: Your code worked by the way, thank you. wanted the classnames so i can single out the opened div and then find the div with the class 'edititable' in it and append an image inside of if.

Comment: @TravisMichaelHeller There's an even simpler way to do that, to get the `editable` element just do `$(".open:visible.editable").append("<img src="" />");`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are multiple DIVs and you want to aggregate all of the unique class names.

```
var result = [];
var uniqueClasses = {};
$(".open:visible").each(function() {
    var lst = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/); // this.className would also work
    for(var i=0; i<lst.length; i++)
        uniqueClasses[lst[i]] = true;
});
for(var k in uniqueClasses)
   result.push("." + k);
console.log(result);
console.log(result.join(""));
```